# Error return truncatechars & safe by using Built-in template tags and filters

Tags: django

I try to Truncates the string and remove the html tags,

First, when I write it this way.

```
{{ post.context|safe }}
```

or

```
{{ post.context |truncatechars:100 }}
```

[image]

The left navigation bar shows normal.

But when I write this, this part of the HTML is gone.

```
{{ post.context |truncatechars:100|safe }}
```

[image]

But I can still find this Html in the source code.

So what can I do to get the correct results?thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to safely show content with **HTML** formatting.

```
{{ post.context|safe }}
```

> If you truncate then some **HTML** tags may not get closed tag and you will get an irregular view.

If you want to strip **HTML** tags, you can strip by **striptags** and truncate characters using **slice** filters.

```
{{post.context|striptags|slice:':300'}}
```

Comment: Oh, that's not good. It's the picture at the beginning, the output is myproject/urls.py from django.conf.urls import url from django.contrib import admin f

Comment: I was right to write it this way. Thank you.   {{ post.context |safe |slice:':100' }}

Comment: Please note that the `striptags` template filter is [not 100% safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags). Consider using something like [bleach](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach) to sanitize text

Comment: @D.T still it will break your layout. Why don't use `truncatewords_html` or `truncatecharss_html` filter like the answer below I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's kinda late to answer if you want to show the safe code with tags then use `{{ post.context|truncatewords_html:30|safe }}` or `{{ post.content|truncatechars_html:100|safe }}`. This won't break your code and will display your desired content.

Answer (score 0):

No need to struggle around. You need to combine `truncate`, `safe`, and `striptags`
Respect the ***order*** below:

```
{{ string_variable|striptags|safe|truncate(100) }}
```

Does that help you?